# iGPU performance is poor when on battery power

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

**Computer: ASUS TUF F17**

**CPU: Intel i5 11400H**

There are similar looking questions on this site, I've read through them all but there didn't seem to have an answer to my question.

**(dedicated)GPU and CPU performace is good on battery, but iGPU is not.** When charging the iGPU is good, but it seems to be limiting itself A LOT when on battery.

**It's not the advanced power options**

**It's not any of the ASUS bloat apps**

I've used MSI afterburner to make sure games and applications that were slowing down were running on the iGPU.

I feel like this is something I can disable: it wouldn't make sense if it was a hardware limitation, the big fat dGPU runs fine after all, and so does the CPU at the same time. **The battery definitely has the juice to run the iGPU faster.** I can throttle the CPU to 800MHz and the iGPU will still be playing catchup in 20 year old games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause has been found to be MSI afterburner: when **hardware control and monitoring** is enabled it signifigantly slows the iGPU. Disabling it, or simply not running MSI afterburner solves the issue.